# How Can I Change Order Total Heading in get_order_item_totals (WooCommerce)?

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I would like to change the "Order Total:" text on the Thank You (/order/received/) page.

I see that it is in the file /includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php (function get_order_item_totals) but I'm not sure how I can override this file.

I also want to override the "Order Total:" text in the email that the admin receives when someone places an order but I assume that this will also be updated as it's the same content as on the Thank You page.

Does anyone know how to change this text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add the following text into your `functions.php` file in your theme. This may not override the text in your email however.

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) { 
$translated = str_ireplace('Order Total', 'New Text Goes Here', $translated); 
return $translated; 
}
```

2) You can edit the template of the emails by going to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/`. Before editing copy this file and paste it to `wp-content/themes/yourthemename/woocommerce/emails/`. More information on the template structure [can be found here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for that! That did exactly what I wanted. Solution 1) did also change the text in the email.